# Create POST Measurement Protocol Hit when new row added to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to send a specific measurement protocol hit to google analytics at certain triggers. I am using an automation to add rows with all the necessary data points to google sheets at these triggers.

These datapoints include - google cid, event label, custom dimensions, etc (no PII).

What I want to do is to be able to create this measurement protocol hit to the google analytics end point based on [the google analytics measurement protocol documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide).

I'm not actually sure where to start here, and if it is even possible and if it's secure to do this?